# How can I open new window in flutter inappwebview package?

Tags: html, flutter, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-inappwebview

I am a junior Flutter app programmer! I have a unsolved issue about Flutter inappwebview's open new tab problem. If you know the solution, please share this to me..

**Problem**:

I want to open phone certification in InAppBroswer. When I operate ‘PASS App’(Phone Certificate Service) , the HTML code’s specific function will be operated.(this function call window.open in HTML) on a new tab page. but, there is a blank page without any information.

**Question:**

How can I make a new tab on webApp page?  I already check the solution that is about making new alert dialog to be a new tab. But I don’t understand  why the 'openDRMOKWindow'(it's HTML code) is not working in the webappview. Please read the HTML code… and if you know the solution to open Phone certificate page on a new page, let me know the solution.

**Info:**

1. If you press one of blue buttons, the Pass (phone certificate app) will be started

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAgx0.png)

2. The HTML code of the blue button is

본인인증

3. openDRMOKWindow function is

   function openDRMOKWindow(type, coworker, service, a_type, kitid, client_key, machine){
   window.name = "parentPage";
   DRMOK_window = window.open('', 'DRMOKWindow', 'width=425, height=550, resizable=0, scrollbars=no, status=0, titlebar=0, toolbar=0, left=435, top=250' );

   ```
        $.ajax({
          url: '/agreements/ctrl/index_session_create.php',
          method : "post",
          dataType : "text",
          data : {
            type : type,
            coworker : coworker,
            service : service,
            a_type : a_type,
            kitid : kitid,
            client_key : client_key,
            machine : machine
          }
        });

        document.form1.action = 'https://www.mobile-ok.com/popup/common/hscert.jsp';
        document.form1.target = 'DRMOKWindow';
        document.form1.submit();
      }
   ```
4. The pass app looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJtFb.png)

**Package version:** **flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2**

**Flutter doctor:**

Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale ko-KR)
• Flutter version 2.8.1 at /Users/taehunku/Downloads/flutter2.2.3
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 77d935af4d (9주 전), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
• Engine revision 890a5fca2e
• Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/taehunku/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-32, build-tools 31.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
• Xcode at /Users/taehunku/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.0)
• VS Code at /Users/taehunku/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.27.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.80

**Full HTML Code:**

```
<html><head>
        <title>개인정보 수집·이용 동의서</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/common.css?ver=3947">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/sweetalert.min.js?ver=6"></script>
    </head>

    
    <body>
        <nav>
          <img src="../../img/index_logo_macrogen.png" class="index-title-image bestf">
        </nav>
        <form name="form1" method="post">
          <article class="article-index">

            <input type="hidden" name="req_info" value="NS0gn4muoWpx/+mOF6iF4oMWKvd9RjnIPUw7yhb20IcLrt782Bz+vB65Fa8AB1JoCJqgds7jyu5z+7dex4hbr5MNTZ4kvkgxn0b0W5k6o5BYMxTh/cAVZ5DzTE98RlTXmTvEuDQ5oSL7sMmKaC4DKEpHWJbs8rikVeLrB0L1tmRKxaczJK7H2Wjws364okzXL+xqR2h4K/AuFf8Qe2Pr03F4XnarjCkeKG0A76Zl9pSMtCls4E/gfiUhoUO6zCpa/Ehz+EhemqsVnESAN/dS/iy/uXiHLVPhDSNhANO+RQaF+OGyv+9eQ/iSirkydjjo9BPDE+0pdBVyYkH4/bBVqQ==">
            <input type="hidden" name="rtn_url" value="https://www.my-genomestory.com/user/agreement_cert_result.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="cpid" value="macrogenmy">

            <img class="image-coworker mx-auto" src="../../img/logo_macrogen.png"><br>
            <p class="font-size-big font-weight-bold text-center text-0">유전자 검사 동의서</p>
            <p class="font-size-small text-center text-1">본인(보호자) 인증 후<br>유전자 검사 신청이 가능합니다.</p>
              <button type="button" onclick="openDRMOKWindow(this.name, 'bestf', 'genome', 'common', '', 'testcode3', 'app')" name="adult" class="button-blue-big color-white font-weight-bold font-size-normal-more mx-auto button-0">본인인증</button>
                              <button type="button" onclick="openDRMOKWindow(this.name, 'bestf', 'genome', 'common', '', 'testcode3', 'app')" name="minor" class="button-blue-big color-white font-weight-bold font-size-normal-more mx-auto button-1 genome">
                  보호자 본인인증<br>
                  <i>(만 19세 미만)</i>
                </button>
              
                            <a href="/agreements/about_DTC?coworker=bestf" class="color-blue font-size-small font-weight-bold text-center mx-auto text-2">DTC 유전자 검사 소개</a>
              <a href="/agreements/download_pdf_guide" class="download_pdf_guide"> 제출한 동의서 pdf 파일 다운로드 가이드</a>
              
              
              <p class="text-center text-box">
                <span class="title">[ 안 내 ]</span><span class="content-1">유전자 검사 동의서는 서비스 진행을 위해<br>필수적으로 제출해야 합니다.</span><span class="content-2">최초 제출 후 5일 이내에는 재작성이 가능합니다.</span>              </p>

            </article>
            
  <footer>
    <p class="font-size-mini font-weight-bold">(주) 마크로젠</p>
    <p class="font-size-mini">주소: 서울특별시 금천구 벚꽃로 254 10층(가산동, 월드메르디앙 1차)<br>
      <a href="tel:+82221807220" onclick="gtag('event','index_footer_전화연결_ko')">02-2180-7220</a> |
      <a href="mailto:hello@macrogen.com" onclick="gtag('event','index_footer_메일보내기_ko')">hello@macrogen.com</a><br>
        카카오톡 ID: <a class="kakao_id" href="http://pf.kakao.com/_xlTEQxl" onclick="gtag(\'event\',\'footer_카카오플러스친구_클릭_ko\')" target="_blank">마이지놈스토리</a></p>
    <p class="font-size-mini font-weight-bold">개인정보처리방침</p>
    <p class="font-size-mini">대표: 이수강 | 사업자등록번호: 208-81-24115</p>
    <p class="font-size-mini color-blue">COPYRIGHT © Macrogen, Inc. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.</p>
  </footer>

        </form>
    

    <script language="javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){
        if('1' == 1 && 'genome' == 'genome'){
          swal({
            icon: 'warning',
            text: "검사 대상자가 19세 이상일 경우 ‘본인인증’을,\n19세 미만일 경우 ‘보호자 본인인증’을 눌러\n유전자 검사 동의서 작성 및 신청을 진행해 주세요."
          })
        }
      })

      function openDRMOKWindow(type, coworker, service, a_type, kitid, client_key, machine){
        window.name = "parentPage";
        DRMOK_window = window.open('', 'DRMOKWindow', 'width=425, height=550, resizable=0, scrollbars=no, status=0, titlebar=0, toolbar=0, left=435, top=250' );

        $.ajax({
          url: '/agreements/ctrl/index_session_create.php',
          method : "post",
          dataType : "text",
          data : {
            type : type,
            coworker : coworker,
            service : service,
            a_type : a_type,
            kitid : kitid,
            client_key : client_key,
            machine : machine
          }
        });

        document.form1.action = 'https://www.mobile-ok.com/popup/common/hscert.jsp';
        document.form1.target = 'DRMOKWindow';
        document.form1.submit();
      }

    </script>


<div class="swal-overlay" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="swal-modal" role="dialog" aria-modal="true"><div class="swal-icon swal-icon--warning">
    <span class="swal-icon--warning__body">
      <span class="swal-icon--warning__dot"></span>
    </span>
  </div><div class="swal-text" style="">검사 대상자가 19세 이상일 경우 ‘본인인증’을,<br>19세 미만일 경우 ‘보호자 본인인증’을 눌러<br>유전자 검사 동의서 작성 및 신청을 진행해 주세요.</div><div class="swal-footer"><div class="swal-button-container">

    <button class="swal-button swal-button--confirm">OK</button>

    <div class="swal-button__loader">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>

  </div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

**Dart Code:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await AndroidInAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }

  runApp( const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;


    InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(

        javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: true,
        javaScriptEnabled: true,
        useOnDownloadStart: true,
        useOnLoadResource: true,
        cacheEnabled: true,
        preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.MOBILE,
        useShouldInterceptAjaxRequest: true,
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: true,
        allowFileAccessFromFileURLs: true,
        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs: true
      ),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
        useHybridComposition: true,
      ),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback: true,
        suppressesIncrementalRendering: true,
        ignoresViewportScaleLimits: true,
        selectionGranularity: IOSWKSelectionGranularity.DYNAMIC,
        isPagingEnabled: true,

        enableViewportScale: true,
        sharedCookiesEnabled: true,
        automaticallyAdjustsScrollIndicatorInsets: true,
        useOnNavigationResponse: true,

        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      ));

  late PullToRefreshController pullToRefreshController;
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;
  final urlController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    pullToRefreshController = PullToRefreshController(
      options: PullToRefreshOptions(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onRefresh: () async {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          webViewController?.reload();
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          webViewController?.loadUrl(
              urlRequest: URLRequest(url: await webViewController?.getUrl()));
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Official InAppWebView website")),
          body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)
                  ),
                  controller: urlController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                  onSubmitted: (value) {
                    var url = Uri.parse(value);
                    if (url.scheme.isEmpty) {
                      url = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + value);
                    }
                    webViewController?.loadUrl(
                        urlRequest: URLRequest(url: url));
                  },
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      InAppWebView(
                        key: webViewKey,
                        initialUrlRequest:
                        URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://www.my-genomestory.com/agreements/index/bestf/?service=genome&clientKey=abcd12345&machine=app")),
                        initialOptions: options,
                        pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
                        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                          webViewController = controller;
                        },
                      onCreateWindow: (InAppWebViewController,createWindowRequest)async{
                   
                          InAppWebViewController.addJavaScriptHandler(handlerName: 'openDRMOKWindow', callback: (args){
                            print(args);
                          });
                        showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) {
                            return AlertDialog(
                              content: Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                height: 400,
                                child: InAppWebView(
                                  // Setting the windowId property is important here!
                                  windowId: createWindowRequest.windowId,
                                  initialUrlRequest:
                                  URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://www.mobile-ok.com/popup/common/hscert.jsp")),
                                  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                                    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(

                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  onWebViewCreated: ( controller) {

                                  },

                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },

                        onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                          setState(() {
                            this.url = url.toString();
                            urlController.text = this.url;
                          });
                        },
                        androidOnPermissionRequest: (controller, origin, resources) async {
                          return PermissionRequestResponse(
                              resources: resources,
                              action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                        },
                        shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
                          var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

                          if (![ "http", "https", "file", "chrome",
                            "data", "javascript", "about"].contains(uri.scheme)) {
                            if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                              // Launch the App
                              await launch(
                                url,
                              );
                              // and cancel the request
                              return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                            }
                          }

                          return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                        },
                        onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                          pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                          setState(() {
                            this.url = url.toString();
                            urlController.text = this.url;
                          });
                        },
                        onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
                          pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                        },
                        onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                          if (progress == 100) {
                            pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                          }
                          setState(() {
                            this.progress = progress / 100;
                            urlController.text = this.url;
                          });
                        },
                        onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                          setState(() {
                            this.url = url.toString();
                            urlController.text = this.url;
                          });
                        },
                        onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                          print(consoleMessage);
                        },
                      ),
                      progress < 1.0
                          ? LinearProgressIndicator(value: progress)
                          : Container(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                ButtonBar(
                  alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      onPressed: () {
                        webViewController?.goBack();
                      },
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                      onPressed: () {
                        webViewController?.goForward();
                      },
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                      onPressed: () {
                        webViewController?.reload();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ]))),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the InAppWebView [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/InAppWebView/shouldOverrideUrlLoading.html) property. This allows the WebView to open the url in a browser.

```dart
shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest) async {
  var url = shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest.url;
  var uri = Uri.parse(url);

  if ((uri.toString()).contains('YOUR_URL')) {
    return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
  } else {
    launchURL(uri.toString());
    return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
  }
}
```